# SQL Server - Round a number when it's one decimal before .50

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I would like to know if there is a way to round a number if it's one decimal before 50.

i.e,

I am using the below code and it works, it gives 8.50:

```
select Round(8.49,1) = 8.50
```

The problem comes when I want to round the below one, I would expect this one to be only 8.48 but results in 8.50 as well.

```
select Round(8.48,1) = 8.50
```

The idea is to keep the 8.48 as it is, but when it's 8.49, it needs to be 8.50.

Comment: Existing question about custom rounding in SQL Server: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63988018/custom-rounding-in-sql

Comment: What happens if it's `8.47` or `8.45`, are you trying to round to nearest `.02` or just that `.49` to `.99` round up?

Answer (score 4):

If you want something other than a standard rounding, you will probably need to use a nested CASE statement.

Maybe take something like the below and tweak it:

```
DECLARE @Num DEC (10,2) = 8.49 --8.48 

SELECT 
CASE 
WHEN @Num - FLOOR(@Num) >= 0.5 THEN ROUND(@Num,1)
WHEN @Num - FLOOR(@Num) = 0.49 THEN FLOOR(@Num) + 0.5 
ELSE @Num
END AS NewValue
```